# Github is setting up submodules where I don't want them

Tags: git, github, restkit

I have an issue with Git where I am attempting to add RestKit as a submodule and it is submoduling my actual code as well.. I've deleted and re-created but still occuring!

This is an image of my github repo...

[image: The checkpoint repo is the one I want as NOT a submodule]

Is this possible to undo? As I seem to keep having the problem when i init the restkit repo as a submodule using: git submodule add git://github.com/RestKit/RestKit.git

It takes my Checkpoint code and somehow turns it into a submodule too..

And the 'Checkpoint' submodule doesn't exist in the .gitmodules file either!

Answer (score 1):

> 'Checkpoint' submodule doesn't exist in the .gitmodules file either!

That means `Checkpoint` has been recorded as a special entry

```
git ls-tree HEAD Checkpoint
 160000 commit c0f065504bb0e8cfa2b107e975bb9dc5a34b0398  Checkpoint
```

You should either reset to a commit where `Checkpoint` wasn't a submodule, or [restore a deleted directory](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/03/18/restoring-a-directory-from-history.html):

```
git checkout <treeish> -- /path/to/dir
```

(with `<treeish>` a commit where Checkpoint isn't a submodule)

Comment: This has happened on git init - there is no point where Checkpoint was not a submodule